# Automate Word Mail Merge as HTML Email with Task Scheduler

Tags: excel, vbscript, ms-word, scheduled-tasks, mailmerge

I am trying to create a simple .vbs file that I can run using task scheduler automatically at a set time that will open a word doc and perform email mail merge to every recipients.

Word doc is already setup with pre-defined fields and data source "re-connection" is included to ensure that source data is setup properly.

I'm having problem running below code, which in turn will open 2 word applications (the master files which contain all records and new 2 pages word file **with only first and last record**).

Please help me debug this code, as I am starting to lose my sanity in getting this fixed.

```
Dim wd As Object
Dim WDoc As Object
Dim strWorkbookName As String

On Error Resume Next
Set wd = CreateObject("Word.Application")
wd.Application.Visible = True

Set WDoc = wd.Documents.Open("C:\Users\Documents\test\test.docx")

strWorkbookName = "C:\Users\Documents\test\test_datasource.xlsx"

WDoc.MailMerge.OpenDataSource _
    Name:=strWorkbookName, _
    ConfirmConversions:=False, _
    ReadOnly:=False, _
    LinkToSource:=True, _
    AddToRecentFiles:=False, _
    Revert:=False, _
    Format:=0, _
    Connection:="Data Source=" & strWorkbookName & ";Mode=Read", _
    SQLStatement:="SELECT * FROM `Summary$`"


With WDoc.MailMerge
    .Destination = wdSendToEmail
    .MailAddressFieldName = "Email"
    .MailSubject = "TEST - EMAIL SUBJECT"
    .SuppressBlankLines = True
    .MailAsAttachment = False
    .MailFormat = wdMailFormatHTML
    With .DataSource
        .FirstRecord = wdDefaultFirstRecord
        .LastRecord = wdDefaultLastRecord
    End With
.Execute
End With


Set wd = Nothing
Set WDoc = Nothing


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably this might suffice:

```
sub M_snb()
  with getobject("C:\Users\Documents\test\test.docx")
    with .mailmerge
      .Destination = 2
      .MailAddressFieldName = "Email"
      .MailSubject = "TEST - EMAIL SUBJECT"
      .SuppressBlankLines = True
      .MailAsAttachment = False
      .MailFormat = 1
      .execute
    end with
    .close 0
  end with
End sub
```

NB. in late binding the Word constants won't be recognised.

Comment: I'll check it out. I am using late binding since I can't access my excel VBA ("Error Accessing the System Registry" pops up everytime I tried to open). Any clue on how to fix this as well?